# XMPPFramework- Error "405" <not-allowed> in File Transfer

Tags: ios, xmpp, file-transfer, xmppframework

I am trying to implement file transfer using XMPPFramework in iOS. I am sending stanzas to user who is in my roster as following.

---

```
-(void)sendFile
{
    NSString *filePath = fileNameToBeUploaded;
    CFStringRef fileExtension = (__bridge CFStringRef)[filePath pathExtension];
    CFStringRef UTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, fileExtension, NULL);
    CFStringRef MIMEType = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(UTI, kUTTagClassMIMEType);
    CFRelease(UTI);
    NSString *MIMETypeString = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)MIMEType;
    NSString *URL = fileNameToBeUploaded;

    NSError *AttributesError = nil;
    NSDictionary *FileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:URL error:&AttributesError];
    NSNumber *FileSizeNumber = [FileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
    NSArray *splitter = [MIMETypeString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
    NSString *extension = [splitter objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString *mediaType = @"image";
    long FileSize = [FileSizeNumber longValue];

    // XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [[self appDelegate].xmppRosterStorage userForJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:self.chatWithUser] xmppStream:[self appDelegate].xmppStream managedObjectContext:[self appDelegate].managedObjectContex_roster];
    // Create message


    self.streamId = [self generateIDWithPrefix:@"ip_"];
    self.requestId = [self generateIDWithPrefix:@"jsi_"];

    NSXMLElement *si = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"si" xmlns:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/si"];
    [si addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:self.streamId];
    [si addAttributeWithName:@"mime-type" stringValue:MIMETypeString];
    [si addAttributeWithName:@"profile" stringValue:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer"];

    NSXMLElement *fileElement = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"file" xmlns:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer"];
    [fileElement addAttributeWithName:@"name" stringValue:[fileNameToBeUploaded lastPathComponent]];
    [fileElement addAttributeWithName:@"size" stringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",FileSize]];
    [fileElement addAttributeWithName:@"desc" stringValue:@""];
    [si addChild:fileElement];

    NSXMLElement *feature = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"feature" xmlns:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg"];

    NSXMLElement *x = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"x" xmlns:@"jabber:x:data"];
    [x addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"from"];

    NSXMLElement *field = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"field"];
    [field addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"list-single"];
    [field addAttributeWithName:@"var" stringValue:@"stream-method"];

    NSXMLElement *option = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"option"];
    NSXMLElement *bs = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"value" xmlns:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"];

    [option addChild:bs];
    [field addChild:option];
    [x addChild:field];
    [feature addChild:x];
    [si addChild:feature];

    XMPPJID *toJid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/iPhone",self.chatWithUser]];
    XMPPIQ *iqtoSend = [XMPPIQ iqWithType:@"set" to:toJid elementID:self.requestId child:si];

    if (self.fileInfo)
    {
        self.fileInfo = nil;
    }

    self.fileInfo = [[FileInfo alloc] initWithFileName:fileNameToBeUploaded mediaType:mediaType mimeType:MIMETypeString size:FileSize localName:fileNameToBeUploaded IQ:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",iqtoSend] fileNameAsSent:fileNameToBeUploaded sender:@""];
    [self appDelegate].isSending = YES;
    [[self appDelegate].xmppStream sendElement:iqtoSend];

}
```

Console shows the following

**Sending stanzas**

```
SEND: <iq type="set" to="tushar@54.186.107.171/iPhone" id="jsi_9579">
        <si xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si" id="ip_4387" mime-type="image/png" profile="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer">
            <file xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer" name="11392014-143906437.png" size="166688" desc=""/>
                <feature xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg">
                    <x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="from">
                        <field type="list-single" var="stream-method">
                            <option>
                                <value xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"/>
                            </option>
                        </field>
                    </x>
                </feature>
            </si>
        </iq>
```

**Response**

```
RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="error" id="jsi_9579" to="dev1@54.186.107.171/55879756" from="tushar@54.186.107.171/iPhone">
    <si xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si" id="ip_4387" mime-type="image/png" profile="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer">
        <file xmlns="http://jabber.org/protovcol/si/profile/file-transfer" name="11392014-143906437.png" size="166688" desc=""/>
            <feature xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg">
                <x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="from">
                    <field type="list-single" var="stream-method">
                        <option>
                            <value xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"/>
                        </option>
                    </field>
                </x>
            </feature>
        </si>
        <error code="405" type="cancel"><not-allowed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
        </error><
    </iq>
```

My JID is dev1@54.186.107.171.
JI of user whom I want to send file is tushar@54.186.107.171.

Why I am getting error 405?
Is any process is required to do file transfer? Have I missed something?

Comment: am  not yet tried file transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct following line

```
[x addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"from"];
```

With

```
[x addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"form"];
```

Here you have written "from" instead of "form". For more details you can visit following link: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0096.html

Comment: thank you for reply.I have achieved file sending from device. can u please share some code for receive file.. thank you

Comment: @ashishchaklasiya I still did not get success for file receiving, but I am searching for it. Once I will find solution, I will post it sure.

Comment: I got solution for file receiving. Now I can send and receive from both entity.... thanks for replay.

Comment: @ashishchaklasiya Very good. Can you post solution about that?

Comment: Yes,but at where I can post this solution.

Comment: @ashishchaklasiya You can answer your own question on this post and accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57245/discussion-between-sunil-z-and-ashish-chaklasiya).

Comment: using xep-0096 u can easily send and receive file.

Comment: @ashishchaklasiya Yes I have used xep-0096 for sending file but how to receive it?

Comment: u r not answering at chat.

Comment: I am getting error 404 item not found error in response how to solve it. can u please help me

Comment: @ashishchaklasiya Give me you email address

Comment: ashish.chaklasiya303@gmail.com

Comment: form your code now i am getting error 406 not acceptable. how can i solve this

Comment: Can you post stanza here?

Comment: let us continue with chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57297/discussion-between-ashish-chaklasiya-and-sunil-z).

Comment: hi sunil. i have completed file transfer. I need few suggestion regarding this can u please help me.

Comment: now i want to notify the user when I am starting to send file. for now, image is displaying while it has been completely received. but I want to notify that user while file sending began. Is this possible. Are you getting my concepet?

Comment: Something like informing that user that one of user in your contact is sending you file...

Comment: the problem was in that host address. that address was server private ip address that no one can use. I have changed proxy65 setting in open fire server. and problem solved. :D

Comment: hmmmm. Also I got your concept. But I have not did implement as like your concept. One thing you can do is you have to check didReceiveIQ method on receiver side. You will get idea from that.

Comment: I know that I have to do that kind of stuff. Let me try it thanks for replay.

Comment: do you know how to send and receive buddy request and how to manage that.

Comment: Can I receive more than one file at a time? if yes, then how it can be achieved. can you please help me.

Comment: Yes, you can transfer more than one file at a time. For that you need to create your own class with handle it. Mean for multiple file transfer you have to create multiple TurnSockets for each file transfer.

Comment: have I do any change in XMPPSIfiletransfer Class?

Comment: Here you have to create and initialize a temporary NSMutableArray object. Then you have to add initilized turnsockets object in that array at - (BOOL)handleServiceDiscoveryRequest:(XMPPIQ*)inIq method. I am not sure about it will working or not.

Comment: It is not working for me. any other solution if you have any idea?

Comment: is it possible with xmppframework to receive muliple file from more than one sender. have any idea any other framework to achieve this. please help me.

Comment: Hi, I am getting 503 service unavaiable while sending file. Can you please suggest me what mistake can be done by me?

Comment: @ashishchaklasiya you got success with file transfer between cross platform. If yes then please give me that demo code if you have. Thanks